# Is "High life expectancy is needed by everyone" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

If I would express an option meaning everyone wants to live longer, how to make such sentence with the phrase *life expectancy*? Does this one sound right?

> High life expectancy is needed by everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll offer a few that sound natural to my ear:

> *We'd all like to increase our life expectancy*.
>
> *Everyone wants a higher life expectancy*.
>
> *No one wants a short life expectancy*.

I wouldn't use the verb *need*. A *need* is a requirement – something you can't do without – while a *life expectancy* is something you cannot control. (Well, you may be able to affect your life expectancy through healthy lifestyle choices, but, if people are dying from a terminal disease, then it doesn't matter how much they "need" a higher life expectancy, they are not going to get it.) The verb *need* is more for sentences like:

> You need flour to bake a cake.
>
> I need a wrench – can you run to the tool shed and bring me my toolbox?
>
> You need to make good lifestyle choices if you want a high life expectancy.